# How can you redefine MPI_FLOAT, MPI_DOUBLE in a typedef way

Tags: c++, types, mpi

I want to do typedef MPI_FLOAT/MPI_DOUBLE in the following way

```
#ifdef DOUBLE_PRECISION
     typedef MPI_DOUBLE MPI_REAL_MYOWN;
#else 
     typedef MPI_FLOAT MPI_REAL_MYOWN;
#endif
```

I am using wrapper mpicxx from mpich.  The idea is that I can now use `MPI_REAL_MYOWN` in my MPI APIs without having to worry about whether I compiled in double or single precision.
When compiling I get an error saying

```
error: expected ')'
  typedef MPI_FLOAT MPI_REAL_MYOWN;
```

Comment: The code your calling may care greatly about whether you pass them a `float` or a `double`. Just saying.

Comment: `MPI_FLOAT` is a constant. It's a number. Like `1006`. It's not a type. You can't "typedef a number", you can't `typedef 1006 MPI_REAL_MYOWN`.

Comment: But you still cannot do something where you have another customised variable that is equivalent to e.g. `MPI_FLOAT`. In Fortran you can do directly `MPI_REAL_MYOWN=MPI_FLOAT`, so I imagined that c++ would allow similar thing

Comment: @KamilCuk Okay, I got what you're saying. How would I define another variable being equivalent to `MPI_FLOAT` so instead of using the latter I use my own named variable

Comment: Using the `MPI_` prefix to name identifiers in user code, i.e., in anything that isn't part of the MPI implementation, is strongly discouraged. Same applies to `mpi_`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MPI_FLOAT` and `MPI_DOUBLE` are [values of type `MPI_Datatype`](https://github.com/trilinos/Trilinos/blob/master/packages/zoltan/siMPI/pyMPI/siMPI/mpi.h#L30). Just create a variable of that type if you wish.

```
#ifdef DOUBLE_PRECISION
const MPI_Datatype MPI_REAL_MYOWN = MPI_DOUBLE;
#else 
const MPI_Datatype MPI_REAL_MYOWN = MPI_FLOAT;
#endif
```

Comment: worked. My I ask if you would recommend having a static?

Comment: "a static"? You mean If I would recommend defining these variable with internal linkage? That depends on the use case, I guess. I guess would go with `static constexpr` if these constants are going to be defined in a header file.

Comment: `MPI_FLOAT` is a `MPI_Datatype` which is an opaque handler. FWIW this is an integer in MPICH and a pointer in Open MPI, but you should not make any assumptions if you want to write portable code.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Thank you!. Just to make sure, the above answer would work fine for any MPI package since we are using the opaque handler?

Comment: Yes, the fix is valid.